# Quick Reference Long Names in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with long and usefully descriptive names. I don't want to have to butcher the names by truncating them and imposing _ in place of spaces as is typical of many recommendations by python users. Is there a way to set up pandas to recognize a truncated column name if the name is sufficient to uniquely identify the columns such as `df.This`, `df.Anot`, `df.Yet`?

Or might there be a way of passing a dictionary to the dataframe class such that using a truncated name will then be automatically associated with the more lengthy reference?

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'This is a long and usefully descriptive name':  [0,1,2]), 
                        'Another long and usefully descriptive name': [1,2,3], 
                        'Yet another long and usefully descriptive name':  [11,22,33]})

   This is a long         Another long         Yet another long
   and usefully           and usefully         and usefully 
   descriptive name       descriptive name     descriptive name
0  0                      1                    11
1  1                      2                    22
2  2                      3                    33
```

Comment: `df.filter(like='This')` or `df.filter(regex='^This')`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in way to do aliases for column names, but it has been suggested before: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11723

For the purposes of doing operations with dataframes, those long names will be a nightmare to reference, so I would keep them in a separate dict and access them as needed (i.e. when outputting to a file or something) rather than having them as the default. Something like this:

```
NAMES = {
    'This': 'This is a long and usefully descriptive name',
    'Another': 'Another long and usefully descriptive name',
    'Yet': 'Yet another long and usefully descriptive name'
}

df = pd.DataFrame({'This': [0,1,2],
                   'Another': [1,2,3],
                   'Yet': [11,22,33]})

df.rename(columns=NAMES).to_csv('nicely-formatted-output.csv')
```